what is a ideal situation in context of camera calibration
I was reading a paper titled
A single-image linear calibration method for camera
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263224118307243
In the methodology section they have mentioned about ideal projection point in reference to camera calibration what does that mean?
Does it mean and my rotation matrix is identity and my translation matrix is 0 vector and my intrensic parameters are exactly what camera specs shows i.e not considering any distortion
I am trying to find the intrensic parameters according to this paper and extrensic parameters using the solvePnp method
